# Is it possible to tell the time spent on a particular Google video hangout?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

Is it possible to generate a report saying on a particular day in a particular hangout, I have spent x minutes on a Google video hangout?

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
Person A's Gmail || Person B's Gmail || Start Time || End Time Total (minutes)||
```

Any ideas?